# In Ruby, why wrap "yield" in a call you are making anyway?

Tags: ruby, yield

I am new to Ruby. I am confused by something I am reading here:

http://alma-connect.github.io/techblog/2014/03/rails-pub-sub.html

They offer this code:

```
# app/pub_sub/publisher.rb
module Publisher
  extend self

  # delegate to ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
  def broadcast_event(event_name, payload={})
    if block_given?
      ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(event_name, payload) do
        yield
      end
    else
      ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(event_name, payload)
    end
  end
end
```

What is the difference between doing this:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(event_name, payload) do
  yield
end
```

versus doing this:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(event_name, payload)
yield
```

If this were another language, I might assume that we first call the method `instrument()`, and then we call yield so as to call the block. But that is not what they wrote. They show yield being nested inside of `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument()`.

Should I assume that `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument()` is returning some kind of iterable, that we will iterate over? Are we calling yield once for every item returned from `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While blocks are frequently used for iteration they have many other uses. One is to ensure proper resource cleanup, for example

```
ActiveRecord::Base.with_connection do
  ...
end
```

Checks out a database connection for the thread, yields to the block and then checks the connection back in.

In the specific case of the instrument method you found what it does is add to the event data it is about to broadcast information about the time it's block took to execute. The actual implementation is more complicated but in broad terms it's not so different to

```
event = Event.new(event_name, payload)
event.start = Time.now
yield 
event.end = Time.now 
event
```

The use of yield allows it to wrap the execution of your code with some timing code. In your second example no block is passed to `instrument`, which detects this and will record it as an event having no duration

Answer (score 0):

The `broadcast_event` method has been designed to accept an optional `block` (which allows you to pass a code block to the method).

`ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument` also takes an optional block.

Your first example simply takes the block passed in to `broadcast_event` and forwards it along to `ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument`. If there's no block, you can't `yield` anything, hence the different calls.